# How to access the value of a variable from a module to my component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

So this is my `app.module.ts` (i've injected `NgxTypeaheadModule` like this)

```
   import { NgxTypeaheadModule } from '../components/common/components/ngx-typeahead/ngx-typeahead'    
   imports: [NgxTypeaheadModule]
```

This is the module (`ngxTypeahead.component.ts`)

> This is **ngxTypeahead.component.ts** file inside the above module

```
export class NgxTypeAheadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      showSuggestions = false;

      somefunc(){
       showSuggestions = true;
   }

}
```

In the above module component file, `showSuggestions variable` will change according to user click.

---

> I'm using the above module in my component file below( `chat.component.ts`)

```
 export class ChatComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
       @ViewChild("input") input: ElementRef;

       onKey(event) {
            if (userInput.length == 0)) {

                this.input.showSuggestions = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my chatComponent.html file

```
 <input #input [(ngModel)]="inputText" ngxTypeahead (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

But if i use `this.input.showSuggestions`, i'm getting the value ,but i'm getting this error

[image]

So Which is the correct way to pass the showSuggestions value from module to my `chat.component.ts` ??

Any suggestions or solution would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `@ViewChild("input") input: NgxTypeAheadComponent;` and get the component instance instead of the element ref, but that's bad practice and a path to violating unidirectional data flow! Can also break change detection, doesn't work with OnPush.

Use @Input instead: `@Input() showSuggestions = false;` and in ChatComponent:

```
<input #input [(ngModel)]="inputText" ngxTypeahead 
(keyup)="onKey($event)" [showSuggestions]="showSuggestions">
```